# How to return a Rust closure to JavaScript via WebAssembly?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

The comments on [closure.rs](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/blob/master/src/closure.rs) are pretty great, however I can't make it work for returning a closure from a WebAssembly library.

I have a function like this:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn start_game(
    start_time: f64,
    screen_width: f32,
    screen_height: f32,
    on_render: &js_sys::Function,
    on_collision: &js_sys::Function,
) -> ClosureTypeHere {
    // ...
}
```

Inside that function I make a closure, assuming `Closure::wrap` is one piece of the puzzle, and copying from closure.rs):

```
let cb = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |time| time * 4.2) as Box<FnMut(f64) -> f64>);
```

How do I return this callback from `start_game` and what should `ClosureTypeHere` be?

The idea is that `start_game` will create local mutable objects - like a camera, and the JavaScript side should be able to call the function Rust returns in order to update that camera.

Comment: *I can't make it work* — why not? What "doesn't work"? Do you expect that a potential answerer to randomly try code until they get some kind of error and hope that it's whatever error you got? Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. Try to reproduce your error in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: There are dozens of ways to fail and it would be silly to show each of those with their specific errors. The accepted answer illustrates quite well where the potential roadblocks are and how to work around them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a good question, and one that has some nuance too! It's worth calling out the [closures example](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/closures.html) in the `wasm-bindgen` guide (and the [section about passing closures to JavaScript](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/passing-rust-closures-to-js.html)) as well, and it'd be good to contribute back to that as well if necessary!

To get you started, though, you can do something like this:

```
use wasm_bindgen::{Closure, JsValue};

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn start_game(
    start_time: f64,
    screen_width: f32,
    screen_height: f32,
    on_render: &js_sys::Function,
    on_collision: &js_sys::Function,
) -> JsValue {
    let cb = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |time| {
        time * 4.2
    }) as Box<FnMut(f64) -> f64>);

    // Extract the `JsValue` from this `Closure`, the handle
    // on a JS function representing the closure
    let ret = cb.as_ref().clone();

    // Once `cb` is dropped it'll "neuter" the closure and
    // cause invocations to throw a JS exception. Memory
    // management here will come later, so just leak it
    // for now.
    cb.forget();

    return ret;
}
```

Above the return value is just a plain-old JS object (here as a `JsValue`) and we create that with the `Closure` type you've seen already. This will allow you to quickly return a closure to JS and you'll be able to call it from JS as well.

You've also asked about storing mutable objects and such, and that can all be done through normal Rust closures, capturing, etc. For example the declaration of `FnMut(f64) -> f64` above is the signature of the JS function, and that can be any set of types such as `FnMut(String, MyCustomWasmBindgenType, f64) ->
Vec<u8>` if you really want. For capturing local objects you can do:

```
let mut camera = Camera::new();
let mut state = State::new();
let cb = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |arg1, arg2| { // note the `move`
    if arg1 {
        camera.update(&arg2);
    } else {
        state.update(&arg2);
    }
}) as Box<_>);
```

(or something like that)

Here the `camera` and `state` variables will be owned by the closure and dropped at the same time. More info about just closures [can be found in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch13-01-closures.html).

It's also worth briefly covering the memory management aspect here. In the
example above we're calling `forget()` which leaks memory and can be a problem if the Rust function is called many times (as it would leak a lot of memory). The fundamental problem here is that there's memory allocated on the WASM heap which the created JS function object references. This allocated memory in theory needs to be deallocated whenever the JS function object is GC'd, but we have no way of knowing when that happens (until [`WeakRef` exists](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-weakrefs)!).

In the meantime we've chosen an alternate strategy. The associated memory is
deallocated whenever the `Closure` type itself is dropped, providing
deterministic destruction. This, however, makes it difficult to work with as we need to figure out manually when to drop the `Closure`. If `forget` doesn't work for your use case, some ideas for dropping the `Closure` are:

- First, if it's a JS closure only invoked once, then you can use `Rc`/`RefCell`
  to drop the `Closure` inside the the closure itself (using some interior
  mutability shenanigans). We should also [eventually
  provide](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/1022) native support
  for `FnOnce` in `wasm-bindgen` as well!
- Next, you can return an auxiliary JS object to Rust which has a manual `free`
  method. For example a `#[wasm_bindgen]`-annotated wrapper. This wrapper would
  then need to be manually freed in JS when appropriate.

If you can get by, `forget` is by far the easiest thing to do for
now, but this is definitely a pain point! We can't wait for `WeakRef` to exist :)

Comment: Any particular reason for the `return ret` at the end of the function?

Comment: Ah that's just my own personal style, not necessary!

Comment: Thanks @alexcrichton - I'll need to print this up and sit with it until I really understand it, and I appreciate the thorough breakdown!

Comment: "In the example above we're calling forget() which leaks memory and can be a problem if the Rust function is called many times (as it would leak a lot of memory)."

I take this to mean that if I'm just calling the function as like a "setup", then it's all good? I.e. calling the closure multiple times is fine?

Comment: Correct, yeah. If the whole function is only called once then you'll only "leak" memory once which arguably isn't a leak at all! The returned closure can be called any number of times though and it won't leak memory per invocation, so you should be good there.

Comment: @alexcrichton any solutions to avoid leaking yet?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from documentation, it isn't supposed to export Rust closures, they only might be passed over as parameters to imported JS functions, but all this happens in Rust code.
https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/passing-rust-closures-to-js.html#passing-rust-closures-to-imported-javascript-functions
I made couple of experiments, and when a Rust function returns the mentioned 'Closure' type, compiler throws exception: `the trait wasm_bindgen::convert::IntoWasmAbi is not implemented for wasm_bindgen::prelude::Closure<(dyn std::ops::FnMut() -> u32 + 'static)>`
In all examples, closures are wrapped into an arbitrary sctuct, but after that you already can't call this on JS side.