# Clousure Invocation Error when Creating a Callback with a Clousure on Mouse Input Event in WASM-Bindgen Rust

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly, onmousemove, wasm-bindgen

I have a Rust program forked from the [WASM-Bindgen "canvas" example](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/tree/master/examples/canvas). I'm trying to call some Rust code on every JavaScript `onmousemove` Event for the `Canvas` Element. My code currently creates the DOM event successfully (as it seems). However, on every event that fires, the Firefox developer edition developer tools' console shows an error:

`Uncaught Error: closure invoked recursively or destroyed already`

Here's part of my code:

```
use std::f64;
use std::sync;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use wasm_bindgen::JsCast;

mod canvas_manager;
use canvas_manager::CanvasManager;

#[wasm_bindgen(start)]
pub fn start() {
    let document = web_sys::window().unwrap().document().unwrap();
    let canvas = document.get_element_by_id("canvas").unwrap();
    let canvas: web_sys::HtmlCanvasElement = canvas
        .dyn_into::<web_sys::HtmlCanvasElement>()
        .map_err(|_| ())
        .unwrap();

    let manager = CanvasManager::new(canvas, 480, 480);

    manager.fill_rect_with_color(210, 12, 60, 6, "#444");
    
    manager.fill_rect_with_color(210, 462, 60, 6, "#444");
    
    manager.fill_rect_with_color(236, 236, 8, 8, "#999");

    manager.clear_canvas();

    let xPos= sync::Arc::from(sync::Mutex::new(Box::new(0f64)));

    let xPosCloned = xPos.clone();

    let a = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move || {
        let mut xPosBox = xPosCloned.lock().unwrap();
        **xPosBox += 1f64;
        //web_sys::console::log_1(&JsValue::from_f64(2.5f64));
    }) as Box<dyn FnMut()>);

    manager.canvas.set_onmousemove(Some(a.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is Mr. Russ ;-). I see you have an answer to your question. It is common courtesy on Stack Overflow to upvote it/accept it if it meets your requirements, or comment on it if it doesn't. :-) I'm sure the answerer would appreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In provided code `a` will be dropped at the end of `start()`.

You can fix that via `a.forget()` but then you'll introduce memory leak.

```
let a = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move || {
    let mut xPosBox = xPosCloned.lock().unwrap();
    **xPosBox += 1f64;
    //web_sys::console::log_1(&JsValue::from_f64(2.5f64));
}) as Box<dyn FnMut()>);

manager.canvas.set_onmousemove(Some(a.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
a.forget();
```

Please take a look at the good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214434/how-to-return-a-rust-closure-to-javascript-via-webassembly/53219594#53219594) how to avoid memory leaking.